# Laravel Pagination Error -- Call to undefined method stdClass::links()

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-pagination

I developed a laravel application and i want to paginate a view,

look my controller.

```
$times=DB::table('timesheets')   
->leftJoin('users', 'timesheets.timesheet_user', '=', 'users.id')
->leftJoin('projects','projects.project_id','=','timesheets.timesheet_project_id')
->where('timesheet_user','=',$user)
->paginate(5);
return View::make('timesheet/index')->with('times',$times)->with('projects',$projects);
```

Getting result finly in view, but when i try to show the links. it showing error like below,

```
   Call to undefined method stdClass::links() 

 <?php echo $times->links(); ?>
```

what is the error in my code ?

THanks

Comment: Could you show view ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its Wrong in my template file.

```
        <tbody>
          @foreach($qualdatas as $qualdata)
           <tr>
             <td>{{$qualdata->qualification_name}}</td>                
           </tr>
          @endforeach 
        </tbody>
       </table>
     {{$qualdatas->links()}}
```

In My template file, The **foreach alias name and array name** are same. Thant is because getting error like this.

When I change the alias name to different, Its working as beautiful. !!!